# How to close the entire application on click?

Tags: android

Is it possible when the user clicks on the **back button** to **shut down the whole application**, not just the activity but the whole application?

[image]

I am currently using the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     finish();
     System.exit(0);
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it shuts down the current activity rather than the application, and it often gets an error.

Probably I was opening activities one over the other without paying attention, maybe that's the problem, I'm pretty new to android

Comment: `finishAffinity()`

Comment: Have you tried this `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this)`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your good reason for overriding the system’s behavior for improving battery life (letting the OS manage the RAM instead of forcing the app to be launched every time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```